# How to add a python element directly to a <img> HTML element?

Tags: python, html, django

I have a little issue, that I'm not able to decide myself.

I'm using Django and trying to add this Python code:

```
{{ question.question_logo }}
```

that means "1", into HTML element this way:

```
<img id = image src ="{% static "polls/images/question_logos/{{ question.question_logo }}.jpg"%}/>
```

To check myself i tried:

```
<img id=i mage src="{% static " polls/images/question_logos/1.jpg " %}"/>
<h1>{{ question.question_logo }}</h1>
```

It works perfectly

I need to let HTML know somehow, that

```
{{ question.question_logo }}
```

is not a raw part of a link

Thank's for your time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do this instead

`<img id="image" src ="{% static "polls/images/question_logos/" %}{{ question.question_logo }}.jpg"/>`

Comment: Shouldn't one need to add quotes around the `id` attribute too?

Comment: In html, it's a best practice to quote attribute values, but it doesn't prevent the attribute from being parsed by the browser. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put quotes around the `id` attribute as well.
This should work perfectly.

```
<img id ="image" src ="{% static "polls/images/question_logos/{{ question.question_logo }}.jpg" %}"/>
```

Comment: @OP, did this work?
Please mark the answer that worked. Thanks.